# Choosing a random number from a set without reptition in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

in Excel, I'm trying to choose a random number from a set without repetition, always starting with the largest available number not yet chosen.

[image: Example]

That's a picture of what I'd like to do, the Outcome table is what I'd like to achieve.  Basically, you have a Selection of different numbers you can choose from in the Selection Column.  I want to fill the Outcome columns with randomly chosen numbers from the Selection column, without repetition, always starting with the largest number from the Selection column, and working down from there.

The "Check" columns exist to determine how many draws there will be.  If the Sum of the Check row is 1, then the outcome for that column will always be 0.8, the highest possible draw from selection.  If the Sum of the check row is 2, then the Outcome cells associated with the Check cells with a value of 1 in that row will be either 0.8 or 0.1 - but I'd like it to be a random draw as to which cell equals 0.8 and 0.1, if that makes sense.

Any sheet-based or VBA insight into how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.  Thank you as always for your help!

Comment: You could create a duplicate "Selection" column wherein you delete the chosen number in every loop to prevent repetition.

Comment: Alex, how exactly would this work?  What if there were three "1"s in a Check row?

Comment: Looks like there is repetition on the rhs in the example? Also, how does random and always starting with the largest number from the Selection column work?

Comment: For each row in Selection column, assign a random number.  Then sort the Selection and Random and Check columns columns based on the Random. Finally, copy the Selection value to the Outcome column when Check value is 1, else move zero.

Comment: @donPablo is this your own new question or what you think the OP should have written?

Comment: @SolarMike What I wrote is the outline for a solution that is random and without repetition.  Could you modify it to say that?

Comment: @donPablo ahh, so if you had put “try this ...” or “you could create..” it would be clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May try

```
Sub RandSel()
Dim Sel As Range, ChkRng As Range, OutRng As Range, RandSel As Double
Dim Sel2 As Range, ChkRng2 As Range, OutRng2 As Range, Cel As Range
Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long, Offs As Long, Sm As Long
RandSel = 0
Set Sel = Range("A2:A6")              ' may change to your requirement
Set ChkRng = Range("E2:I7")           ' may change to your requirement 
Set OutRng = Range("K2:O7")           ' may change to your requirement

For Rw = 1 To OutRng.Rows.Count
Set ChkRng2 = Range(ChkRng(Rw, 1), ChkRng(Rw, ChkRng.Columns.Count))  'set range to the row only to evelte repeatation of value
Set OutRng2 = Range(OutRng(Rw, 1), OutRng(Rw, OutRng.Columns.Count)) 'set range to the row only to evelte repeatation of value
    For Col = 1 To OutRng.Columns.Count
    Sm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ChkRng2)
        If ChkRng(Rw, Col).Value = 0 Or Sm = 0 Then
        RandSel = 0
        Else
        Set Sel = Range(Sel(1, 1), Sel(Sm, 1))
        idx = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Sm)
        RandSel = Sel(idx, 1)

        If Col > 1 Then
        Set OutRng2 = Range(OutRng(Rw, 1), OutRng(Rw, Col - 1)) ' set to upto the column in process
        Do While WorksheetFunction.CountIf(OutRng2, RandSel) > 0 ' check only after 1st col
            Set Sel2 = Nothing                                      ' set Sel to range Sel2 - Used value
                For Each Cel In Sel.Cells
                 If Cel.Value <> RandSel Then
                        If Sel2 Is Nothing Then
                        Set Sel2 = Cel
                        Else
                        Set Sel2 = Union(Sel2, Cel)
                        Sm = Sel2.Cells.Count
                        End If
                        End If
                    Next
                    If Sm > 1 Then
                    idx = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Sm)
                    Else
                    idx = 1
                    End If
                RandSel = Sel2(idx, 1)
            Loop
        End If
    End If
    OutRng(Rw, Col).Value = RandSel
    Next Col
Next Rw
End Sub
```

Comment: So @Ahmed AU, thank you, that worked fantastically.  Really appreciate the help!